# Finding a local minimiser

Tags: optimization

I have a function $$f(x)=3e^{2x} -10x -7x^2$$
Using the grid search method with three internal points and using [0,1] as the starting interval, I get the solution 1.3964 after 4 iterations.

Could anyone verify this please?

Comment: If you want a verification and only that. http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eecvsatilo2

Comment: I subbed 1.3964 into dfx and it came out as 68.  Thats why I kind of want someone to do the golden search method